# <br> between angular expression

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, data-binding

I have an expression like this below:

```
<td>{{student.name}}<br>{{student.age}}<br>{{student.fathername}}</td>
```

While displaying it shows like:

```
shane<br>26<br>greg
```

Is it possible i can break this into like below in a single row itself:

```
shane
26
greg
```

Comment: Don't see how you would get that result unless you had the html in a string somewhere. Show all relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-bind-html` with string concatenation for rendering it.

```
ng-bind-html="student.name+ '<br>'+ student.age + '<br>' + student.fathername"
```

Comment: Can we by any chance apply filters here?

Comment: @Shane could you update your question with more code please.. so I can contrast on your point.

Comment: Its just an ng-repeat... nothing else, i am using filters like currency {{somevalue | currency}}, now the br tags with your ng-bind-html works like charm... just wanted to know if we could apply filters here?

Comment: @Shane yes, you could do that too..if code is repeating quite often. but while doing that you need to return the html response using `$sce.trustAsHtml` method to make that html sanitize and valid